# Power system model setup with GEKKO

Tags: gekko

I'm trying to optimize a power system with [GEKKO](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). In specific using MPC to the [IEEE 14 bus](http://labs.ece.uw.edu/pstca/pf14/pg_tca14bus.htm) test case.

The system comprises 14 buses and the model consists of the state variables `theta` and `omega` (power angle and spinning frequency of the generator respectively) and the algebraic eqs.

The algebraic equations correspond to the DC approximation, i.e., linear approximation of the power flow equation. In the eqs below `w^ref` is the target electrical frequency of 60 Hz. `P` is the vector of real power at each bus. `B` is the susceptance matrix of the system. `u` is the control input which corresponds to the mechanical power of the generators.

The objective is to reach `w^ref` and power angles close to `0` for each bus by manipulating the mechanical power `u`.

[image]

The error I'm getting is (the code is below):

```py
in dc_opf
 m.solve(disp=True,debug=True) File
"/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gekko/gekko.py", line 1957, in solve
  self._build_model() File
"/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gekko/gk_write_files.py", line 33, in _build_model
  if not (parameter.VALUE==None): File
"/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gekko/gk_operators.py", line 25, in __len__
  return len(self.value) File
"/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gekko/gk_operators.py", line 144, in __len__
  return len(self.value)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

**My question is where is the coding wrong?**

I have two function `dc_opf()` and `dc_mats(mat,mode)`. The former is where the optimization happens. The latter is a helper function to populate the `P` and `B` matrices.

My code is:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

def dc_opf():
 m = GEKKO(remote=False)
 omega_ref =  m.Param(value=60.) #m.Array(m.FV,(14,1))
 omega_hi = m.Param(value=61.)
 omega_lo = m.Param(value=59.)
 H =  m.Array(m.FV,(14,1))
 Hs = [5.15, 6.54, 6.54, 0., 0., 5.06, 0., 5.06,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.] #Moment of inertia
 for i in range(14):
  H[i,0].value= Hs[i]

 P = m.Array(m.FV,(14,1))
 P = dc_mats(P, 'Pow_full') 

 theta = m.Array(m.SV,(14,1))
 u = m.Array(m.CV,(14,1))
 for i in range(14):
  u[i,0].STATUS = 1
 omega = m.Array(m.SV,(14,1))

 B = m.Array(m.FV,(14,14))
 B = dc_mats(B, 'B_full')

 # Soft constraints
 oH = m.CV(value=0)
 oL = m.CV(value=0)

 oH.SPHI=0; oH.WSPHI=100; oH.WSPLO=0  ; oH.STATUS = 1
 oL.SPLO=0; oL.WSPHI=0  ; oL.WSPLO=100; oL.STATUS = 1

 m.Equations([oH==omega-omega_hi,oL==omega-omega_lo])
 m.Equations([theta[i,0].dt() == omega-omega_ref for i in range(14)])
 m.Equations([omega[i,0].dt() == (u-P)/(2.0*H) for i in range(14)])
 m.Equation(P == B*theta)
 m.Minimize((theta) +  (omega-omega_ref) +  (u-P))
 m.options.IMODE = 6
 m.solve(disp=True,debug=True)

def dc_mats(mat,mode):
 ppc = {"version": '2'}
 ppc["baseMVA"] = 100.0 # system MVA base
 ppc['branch'] = np.array([
        [1,   2, 0.01938, 0.05917, 0.0528, 9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [1,   5, 0.05403, 0.22304, 0.0492, 9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [2,   3, 0.04699, 0.19797, 0.0438, 9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [2,   4, 0.05811, 0.17632, 0.034,  9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [2,   5, 0.05695, 0.17388, 0.0346, 9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [3,   4, 0.06701, 0.17103, 0.0128, 9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [4,   5, 0.01335, 0.04211, 0,      9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [4,   7, 0,       0.20912, 0,      9900, 0, 0, 0.978, 0, 1, -360, 360],
        [4,   9, 0,       0.55618, 0,      9900, 0, 0, 0.969, 0, 1, -360, 360],
        [5,   6, 0,       0.25202, 0,      9900, 0, 0, 0.932, 0, 1, -360, 360],
        [6,  11, 0.09498, 0.1989,  0,      9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [6,  12, 0.12291, 0.25581, 0,      9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [6,  13, 0.06615, 0.13027, 0,      9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [7,   8, 0,       0.17615, 0,      9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [7,   9, 0,       0.11001, 0,      9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [9,  10, 0.03181, 0.0845,  0,      9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [9,  14, 0.12711, 0.27038, 0,      9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [10, 11, 0.08205, 0.19207, 0,      9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [12, 13, 0.22092, 0.19988, 0,      9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360],
        [13, 14, 0.17093, 0.34802, 0,      9900, 0, 0, 0,     0, 1, -360, 360]])

 ppc['bus'] = np.array([
        [1,  3,  0,    0,   0, 0,  1, 1.06,    0,    0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 232.4],
        [2,  2, 21.7, 12.7, 0, 0,  1, 1.045,  -4.98, 0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 40.],
        [3,  2, 94.2, 19,   0, 0,  1, 1.01,  -12.72, 0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 0.],
        [4,  1, 47.8, -3.9, 0, 0,  1, 1.019, -10.33, 0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 0.],
        [5,  1,  7.6,  1.6, 0, 0,  1, 1.02,   -8.78, 0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 0.],
        [6,  2, 11.2,  7.5, 0, 0,  1, 1.07,  -14.22, 0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 0.],
        [7,  1,  0,    0,   0, 0,  1, 1.062, -13.37, 0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 0.],
        [8,  2,  0,    0,   0, 0,  1, 1.09,  -13.36, 0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 0.],
        [9,  1, 29.5, 16.6, 0, 19, 1, 1.056, -14.94, 0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 0.],
        [10, 1,  9,    5.8, 0, 0,  1, 1.051, -15.1,  0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 0.],
        [11, 1,  3.5,  1.8, 0, 0,  1, 1.057, -14.79, 0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 0.],
        [12, 1,  6.1,  1.6, 0, 0,  1, 1.055, -15.07, 0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 0.],
        [13, 1, 13.5,  5.8, 0, 0,  1, 1.05,  -15.16, 0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 0.],
        [14, 1, 14.9,  5,   0, 0,  1, 1.036, -16.04, 0, 1, 1.06, 0.94, 0.]])

 if(mode=='Pow_full'): #This If is for the real power vector P
  for r in range(14):
   mat[r,0].value = ppc['bus'][r][2] +ppc['bus'][r][-1]

 elif(mode=='B_full'): #This is the susceptance matrix
  for r in range(14):
   for c in range(14):
    mat[r,c].value = 0.
  for r in range(ppc['branch'].shape[0]):
   fom = int(ppc['branch'][r][0])-1 #the from bus
   tom = int(ppc['branch'][r][1])-1 #the to bus
   mat[fom,tom].value = 1./ppc['branch'][r][3] 
   mat[tom,fom].value = 1./ppc['branch'][r][3] 
  for j in range(14):
   mat[j,j].value = sum(mat[j])
 else:
  pass
 return mat
```

**Thanks**

**UPDATE 1**

In the function `dc_mats(mat,mode)` This part of the code is causing troubles:

```py
for j in range(14):
 mat[j,j].value = sum(mat[j])
```

The `sum` is returning a datatype `instance`. But even if I comment this piece of code I still have issues in the optimization part with the `m.arrays` I'm defining.

Comment: I found it quite hard to figure out what `gekko` is in this case. Although I cannot help you with your problem it might still be helpful if you add a bit more info/context/links.

Comment: Thanks. I just added a link to GEKKO's website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were quite a few issues with your application so I created a simpler application that uses random initial values and ones for the matrices. Your application is a linear system of equations so it should solve quickly and reliably. You can hopefully fill in your problem specific information into the example below. The optimizer adjusts the value of `u` to drive `w` to the desired setpoint target `wref`.

[image: optimal control]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = GEKKO()
n = 14
B = np.ones((n,n))
H = np.ones(n)
wref = 0.5

u = m.Array(m.MV,n,lb=0,ub=1)
w = m.Array(m.Var,n)
theta = m.Array(m.Var,n)
P = np.dot(B,theta)

m.Equations([theta[i].dt()==w[i]-wref for i in range(n)])
m.Equations([w[i].dt()==(u[i]-P[i])/(2*H[i]) for i in range(n)])

[m.Minimize((w[i]-wref)**2) for i in range(n)]

m.time = np.linspace(0,5)

for i in range(n):
    u[i].STATUS = 1
    w[i].value = np.random.rand()
    theta[i].value = np.random.rand()

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1)
for i in range(n):
    ax1.plot(m.time,u[i].value)
    ax2.plot(m.time,w[i].value)
    ax3.plot(m.time,theta[i].value)
ax1.set_ylabel('u')
ax2.set_ylabel('w')
ax3.set_ylabel('theta')
ax2.plot([0,max(m.time)],[wref,wref],'k--',lw=3,label='Target')
ax2.legend()
ax3.set_xlabel('time')
plt.show()
```

I recommend that you look at similar [tutorial applications (see number 17 on MPC)](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization) or the applications on the [Machine Learning and Dynamic Optimization course](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/InvertedPendulum). Thanks for sharing this interesting application.

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks for taking the time. You are so right. One of the issues that you alluded to is the fact that in my code I've zeros in the `H` vector. Just know I realized that this was causing **division by zero**. Now, I added everything including the algebraic eqs: `m.Equations([P[i] == np.dot(B,theta)[i] for i in range(n)])` and the remaining terms in the objective fun: `[m.Minimize((w[i]-wref)**2 + theta[i]+ (u[i]-P[i])**2) for i in range(n)]`

Comment: I'll definitely watch again the tutorials. The part the confuses me the most is **when to declare the variables as a GEKKO array and when not**. As an example, I couldn't use  GEKKO's data structures for matrix `B` and an array for `H` because for some reason the way I did it just didn't work. Based on your answer a list works better and that's what I just did and works great.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. You only need to declare variables as Gekko types when they are changed by the optimizer (m.Var, m.SV, m.CV) or your need them as parameters (m.Param, m.FV, m.MV) to update the values as inputs between simulations or decision variables. More information on these types is here: https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/INFO and here: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ModelFormulation